# Users cannot login after Upgrade to 7

Tags: 7, users, upgrading

I have upgraded a D6 to D7 site on my localhost. After upgrade I can login using admin credentials as per usual. I have disabled Clean URLs and I see that users are in detabase. Actually all works well however when I try to log in to a user account, I get:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later
```

I get this error also, when I create a user from admin panel. 
I tested [a lot of suggestions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4158/i-cannot-log-into-after-migration?rq=1) but none helped. So appreciate your hints.

Comment: Well, I found a solution: as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/19113091/727695 I added some description to error and figured out that messaging module causes the problem. I disabled messaging, and could login afterwards

Comment: post it as answer and include the essential part of that link.

Comment: @Bala: the answer added

Answer (score 5):

To figure out what was the problem, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19113091/727695) I opened include/error.inc

and replaced

```
print theme('maintenance_page', array('content' => t('The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.')));
```

with

```
print theme('maintenance_page', array('content' => t('The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.'.$fatal.' '.var_export($error,true))));
```

The new command prints out some useful info that can be used to debug. In my case, it turned out that messaging module caused the problem. I disabled messaging, and could login afterwards.

Note: before going to production, switch back to original error.inc, since the error outputs can be a gift to attackers.